# Get day of year from giant list of years, months, and days

Tags: python, date, datetime, large-data

I have 3 giant lists (30,000,000+ elements long) named `year`, `month`, and `day` that correspond to the year, month, and day of the month, respectively. The three lists together represent a long list of dates. I need to get the day of the year for each date.

My fist thought was to convert the 3 lists onto a list of datetime objects, and then use the method outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python) thread:

```
day_of_year = datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday
```

However, doing this appears to takes far too long.

```
def f():
    DOY = [datetime.datetime(y,m,d).timetuple().tm_yday for y,m,d in zip(year,month,day)]

%timeit f()
1 loop, best of 3: 54.2 s per loop
```

I also tried to use the method outlined in the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165223/convert-numpy-array-to-list-of-datetimes) to get quickly an array of datetime64's, but I'm unsure how to then get day of the year with this.

Comment: If you're using Python 2, replace `zip` with `itertools.izip`, which builds the triplets on-the-fly, unlike `zip`, which returns a list. On Python 3 `zip` is fine.

Comment: to "get day of the year with this", converting from `numpy.datetime64` to `datetime.datetime` then call its `.timetuple().tm_yday`, seems to work: `import pandas as pd;

as_dt_object = results[0].astype(datetime.datetime);

print type(results[0]), results[0] , 'day of year: ', type(as_dt_object.timetuple().tm_yday), as_dt_object.timetuple().tm_yday`, output: `<type 'numpy.datetime64'> 2015-01-01T23:04:59 day of year:  <type 'int'> 1` -- basically says `2015-01-01T23:04:59` is the `1` day of year.